# Java Process consumes more then 2 GB of memory

Tags: java, jvm

The Java Process of JacORB notification service consumes about 2 GB of memory in Windows 2008. From YourKit I came to know that the Java Heap does not exceed 30 MB. So I concluded that there is no leak in the Java Heap. I would like to know how to find where is memory getting consumed. I read a few articles on the internet talking about the Java Native Heap. How to conclude if there is a leak in the Native Heap? We are using JRE 1.6 from Oracle (sun).

Answer (score 0):

Exceptionally good tool for analyzing memory leaks in Java is [Memory Analyzer](http://www.eclipse.org/mat/). It could be downloaded as an *Eclipse plugin*, or as a *standalone application*. However, I recommend the latter. Check it out. It also has very good help pages.

Comment: Isn't that the same as any other memory profiler? Does it support viewing/troubleshooting native memory used by the Java application?

Comment: Not sure about *native* memory (I haven't used it for a while), but it does let you analyze possible memory leaks.

Comment: Well, the original question mentions problem with Native Heap, hence my question.

Comment: Maybe take a look at [this](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/ieduasst/v1r1m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.iea.java/java/6.0/MonitorDebug/3-ProfilingNativeMemoryUsage/player.html) presentation. It gives some general ideas.

Comment: Thanks . Here I am not confirming about there is problem with Native Heap. But From Your Kit its very clear there in no leak in Java Heap (which can be set using -Xmx ) . Do you have any idea apart from Native Heap , PermGen where else memory can be cosumed by java process. From Your Kit I could make out even Non-Heap memory is not consumin too much of memory. Where else memory is getting consumed ?